# how should I download Pygame?

Tags: python, windows, download, pygame

I want to start learning how to use Pygame.
I haven't downloaded the actual file because I don't want to download a version that is old or not recommended. I'm using Python 3.4.

Which file should I download? The last one in the windows section below source?

`pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi 6.4MB`

Also do I need to download any other software to make something in it?
Other than of course the software for my music and graphics to put in.

Comment: Did you look up a tutorial for downloading pygame?

Comment: It's as easy as reading the ReadMe file in any package. Plus installing the "Latest Stable" or if not available new listing is recommended.

Comment: I don't know if there could even be a tutorial for something like this. Just go to the official site and download it.

Comment: There is a version of Pygame for Python 3.4 available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). Make sure you download the 32-bit edition.

Comment: The html file for installation notes doesn't open for me only shows a 404 error page :/

Comment: @Zenohm The file you sent is a file download in a different size from the pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi 6.4MB

Comment: @mman1235 And? You're using Python 3.4, that is a version of Pygame which is adapted to work with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is by many the preferred way to install python libraries and modules.
It is included by default with the Python binary installers since Python 3.4.

I believe you can simply install it with the command:

```
pip install pygame
```

If this does not work, you could just take the default approach which was mentioned in the comments. Download the latest stable version for a 32 bit system.
Once downloaded, install it and test if it works by running:

```
import pygame
```

If nothing appears after running it, then you know Pygame has successfully been installed. Good job!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers :)

Comment: I think I'll just try downloading pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi 6.4MB  and see what happens